# Running two tensorflow graphs at a time

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained 2 models for slightly different OCR tasks and I would like to run them both at the same time in a production system.

I have a class that starts a session and loads the saved model. The problem I am having is that the 2 models have variables saved with the same name so they are conflicting when I try to load them in.

Is there a way to run them each in their own session or on their own graph?

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue? By any chance did you try using two graphs?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option would be to build the two models in different graphs and start separate sessions for each graph. However, each session owns its devices (CPU and possibly GPU), so you would have separate thread pools for each model, and this might cause suboptimal scheduling behavior. Careful use of the `tf.Session` configuration options would be necessary to get good performance.

Alternatively, you could combine the two models in the same graph and use a single session. As you point out, the variables for the two models would necessarily have different names. Therefore, to make this work, you would need to provide an explicit name-to-`Variable` mapping when you [construct the `tf.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.__init__) for loading in the model.

Comment: If the OP is in charge of creating the models, then would it be sufficient to create each of them underneath a different `name_scope`?  It's not as robust as adding an explicit prefix upon loading, but it might work well enough in a controlled situation.

Comment: How do you combine two models exactly?