# Shut down server in TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, grpc

When we want to use distributed TensorFlow, we will create a parameter server using

```
tf.train.Server.join()
```

However, I can't find any way to shut down the server except killing the processing. The TensorFlow documentation for join() is

```
Blocks until the server has shut down.
This method currently blocks forever.
```

This is quite bothering to me because I would like to create many servers for computation and shut them down when everything finishes.

Is there possible solutions for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can have parameter server processes die on demand by using `session.run(dequeue_op)` instead of `server.join()` and having another process enqueue something onto that queue when you want this process to die.

So for `k` parameter server shards you could create `k` queues, with unique  `shared_name` property and try to `dequeue` from that queue. When you want to bring down the servers, you loop over all queues and `enqueue` a token onto each queue. This would cause `session.run` to unblock and Python process will run to the end and quit, bringing down the server.

Below is a self-contained example with 2 shards taken from:
https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/82a5b5302449530ca5ff59df520c369e

(for multi worker/multi shard example, see https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/ea1b1bae0a75c4aae593df7eca72d9ca)

```
import subprocess
import tensorflow as tf
import time
import sys

flags = tf.flags
flags.DEFINE_string("port1", "12222", "port of worker1")
flags.DEFINE_string("port2", "12223", "port of worker2")
flags.DEFINE_string("task", "", "internal use")
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

# setup local cluster from flags
host = "127.0.0.1:"
cluster = {"worker": [host+FLAGS.port1, host+FLAGS.port2]}
clusterspec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster).as_cluster_def()

if __name__=='__main__':
  if not FLAGS.task:  # start servers and run client

      # launch distributed service
      def runcmd(cmd): subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
      runcmd("python %s --task=0"%(sys.argv[0]))
      runcmd("python %s --task=1"%(sys.argv[0]))
      time.sleep(1)

      # bring down distributed service
      sess = tf.Session("grpc://"+host+FLAGS.port1)
      queue0 = tf.FIFOQueue(1, tf.int32, shared_name="queue0")
      queue1 = tf.FIFOQueue(1, tf.int32, shared_name="queue1")
      with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
          add_op0 = tf.add(tf.ones(()), tf.ones(()))
      with tf.device("/job:worker/task:1"):
          add_op1 = tf.add(tf.ones(()), tf.ones(()))

      print("Running computation on server 0")
      print(sess.run(add_op0))
      print("Running computation on server 1")
      print(sess.run(add_op1))

      print("Bringing down server 0")
      sess.run(queue0.enqueue(1))
      print("Bringing down server 1")
      sess.run(queue1.enqueue(1))

  else: # Launch TensorFlow server
    server = tf.train.Server(clusterspec, config=None,
                             job_name="worker",
                             task_index=int(FLAGS.task))
    print("Starting server "+FLAGS.task)
    sess = tf.Session(server.target)
    queue = tf.FIFOQueue(1, tf.int32, shared_name="queue"+FLAGS.task)
    sess.run(queue.dequeue())
    print("Terminating server"+FLAGS.task)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works very well. But I met some problems when try to adapt to the example using `tf.Supervisor` (the one on TF website). The graph will be `finalized` as soon as I instantiate a `supervisor` object. Thus we can't enqueue after training. Using two graphs may work but according to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34249940/4811003), it may influence performance. Is there a good solution?

Comment: `queue0.enqueue(1)` actually creates an enqueue op and modifies the graph. You can instead do `op1=queue0.enqueue(1); <finalize>; sess.run(op1)`

Comment: Both enqueue ops are executed on a session with the `127.0.0.1:12222` target, but one of the dequeue ops is executed on a session with the `127.0.0.1:12223` target. Does this distinction not matter? Why?

Comment: The distinction should not matter -- both workers provide master interface, so you are free to choose which one to connect to

Answer (score 5):

This page appears pretty often on Google, so I thought I would try to improve on [Yaroslav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40186129) by providing what I hope is a more clear answer for those just getting into distributed Tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import threading

def main(job_name, task):
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({
        'ps': ['localhost:22222', 'localhost:22223'],
        'worker': ['localhost: 22224','localhost: 22225','localhost: 22226']
    })

    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=job_name, task_index=task)

    if job_name == 'ps':
        # create a shared queue on the parameter server which is visible on /job:ps/task:%d
        with tf.device('/job:ps/task:%d' % task):
            queue = tf.FIFOQueue(cluster.num_tasks('worker'), tf.int32, shared_name='done_queue%d' % task)

        # wait for the queue to be filled
        with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
            for i in range(cluster.num_tasks('worker')):
                sess.run(queue.dequeue())
                print('ps:%d received "done" from worker:%d' % (task, i))
            print('ps:%d quitting' % task)

    elif job_name == 'worker':
        queues = []
        # create a shared queue on the worker which is visible on /job:ps/task:%d
        for i in range(cluster.num_tasks('ps')):
            with tf.device('/job:ps/task:%d' % i):
                queues.append(tf.FIFOQueue(cluster.num_tasks('worker'), tf.int32, shared_name='done_queue%d' % i))

        # fill the queue
        with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
            for i in range(cluster.num_tasks('ps')):
                _, size = sess.run([queues[i].enqueue(task), queues[i].size()])
                print('Worker:%d sending "done" to ps:%d [elements=%d]' % (task, i, size))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=('ps', 0)),
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=('ps', 1)),
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=('worker', 0)),
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=('worker', 1)),
        threading.Thread(target=main, args=('worker', 2))]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

It's pretty simple to extend upon the "canonical" [Distributed Tensorflow example](https://web.archive.org/web/20180125020817/https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) by replacing the worker section of the code with this snippet:

```
    # create a worker that does nothing
    elif job_name == 'worker':
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device='/job:worker/task:%d' % task, cluster=cluster)):
            global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
            no_op = tf.no_op()

        done_ops = []
        # create a shared queue on the worker which is visible on /job:ps/task:%d
        for i in range(cluster.num_tasks('ps')):
            with tf.device('/job:ps/task:%d' % i):
                done_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(cluster.num_tasks('worker'), tf.int32, shared_name='done_queue' + str(i))
                done_ops.append(done_queue.enqueue(task))

        hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=1),
               tf.train.FinalOpsHook([done_ops])]

        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                               is_chief=(task == 0),
                                               hooks=hooks) as sess:
            sess.run([no_op])
```

Note that the MonitoredTrainingSession version seems to be much slower at connecting all of the workers together.

Comment: Thanks, it work! But when the code has some errors, it seems this queue will not shut down ps server, right? I am not familiar with tf, so how could the code shut down ps server if there is an error?

Comment: Some kinds of errors are unrecoverable (like a worker machine crashing), so at the end of the day you might do something simple like have a timeout of 24hrs, or perform a liveness check on a separate thread by pinging a liveness endpoint. Fault-tolerant systems are a complicated but orthogonal issue and deserve their own questions and answers

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no clean way to shut down a TensorFlow gRPC server. It *is* possible to [shut down a gRPC server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708349/3574081), but doing it safely requires additional memory management for all of the in-flight request and response buffers, which would require a lot of additional plumbing (of the worst kind: asynchronous shared memory management...) for a feature that nobody had requested—until now!

In practice you should be able to use the same `tf.train.Server` object for many different computations. If this doesn't work for your use case, please feel free to [open an GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) and tell us more about your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what would you do if you use the example in the documentation of distributed Tensorflow? I mean, after the computation, the two worker servers finish while two parameter servers remain running.

Comment: For the moment, I kill those processes of parameter server from command line. I wonder if it is safe?

Comment: But if I don't kill the servers after a complete training, then the variables inside the ps will influence the next training. Is it the case?

Comment: One more question, when I search for the solutions, it seems the C++ implementation of Tensorflow allows you to shut down the server. Is this the case?

Comment: Killing the parameter servers from the command line is safe. (Typically we use a cluster manager to do this for us, but killing a server manually should work.) You are correct that parameter server variables will persist between training training runs. If you want to avoid this, either use a `with tf.container():` block with different container names in your different programs, or call `tf.Session.reset()` between training runs. Finally, the C++ server shutdown code is implemented, but not heavily tested. In particular, you have to make sure all clients disconnect before shutting down.